# The Witness marsh puzzle: Valid solution not accepted? [SPOILERS]

Tags: the-witness

I breezed through most of the Marsh area, then got stuck for *hours* on the puzzle below before giving up and looking up the answer online. I was frustrated to find that the "correct" answer appears to operate on logic that I thought I had already tested and rejected.

Here's my current understanding of how the blocks work in the puzzle below:

- You must place all yellow blocks in some configuration on the grid, then trace an outline around them. Yellow blocks can't overlap.
- For the purposes of this specific puzzle, all blocks "mesh" into 1 large outline, and none can be rotated.
- All yellow and blue blocks must be included in the overall outline shape.
- For each blue empty *individual square* included in the total shape, you must remove 1 square from a yellow shape before placing it.

Here's the accepted solution, which is pretty straightforward: the bottom-left yellow block sits in the bottom-left corner, with all but the corner square removed; the bottom-right block sits in the bottom-right corner, with no squares removed; and the top-right yellow block sits all the way in the top right corner, with the bottom square removed.

[image]

And here's another solution I had already tried, that was rejected, leading me to make incorrect conclusions about how the blue empty blocks worked. As far as I can tell, this is also pretty straightforward: the bottom-left block sits in the bottom-left corner, with all but the corner square removed; the bottom-right  block sits in the bottom-right corner, with no squares removed; and the top-right yellow block stands in the middle, with its top-left square removed.

[image]

So my question is: Why is solution 1 accepted but solution 2 rejected? Am I misunderstanding the logic of this puzzle? (I don't mind spoilers at this point, I'm just desperate to sort out whether this is a bug or a genuine confusion on my part!)

Comment: If blue shape doesn't matter, why they would put blue dots in different shapes? Think about it. Also there are other moments in The Witness when you would think "that's a valid solution, but it is not accepted, it must be bug" - believe me - it is not bug.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That's because the blue squares are "stuck together".
In this state, you need to remove 4 squares in a square shape, not just any 4 squares.

You're wrong in your assumption of why the 1st answer works.
What really happens is this :

- Bottom left block at the bottom right (red dots).
- Bottom right block at the bottom left (green dots).
- Top right block at the top right corner (purple dots).
- Square removed (blue dots).

[image: Solution]

By doing that, you merge the 2 bottom blocks (imagine the middle part with 2 blocks on top of one another).
That allows you to remove the 4 blocks in a square pattern (blue dots).